# Windows 7 64, how do I use more than 2 GB in C++

Tags: c++, memory, sublimetext2, ram

I am using Sublime Text 2 to write / compile / run C++ code. However once the program uses ~2 GB memory, it quits. I have more than enough memory. How do I increase this limit?

Comment: You can't, you need to use shared memory and map sections in and out

Comment: You need a compiler that outputs 64-bit executable/library.

Comment: cant you build it in 64 bit configuration?

Comment: How do I know if my compiler does that?

Comment: I have: "gcc (GCC) 4.7.2"

Comment: Assuming the compiler is built with the correct options, you should just need to add `-m64` to the flags passed to the compile options. Not sure how you adjust such things in Sublime.

Comment: @paulm: Partially true if the application is 32-bit, but you could get up to nearly 4GB by adding /LARGEADDRESSAWARE (or whatever that feature is called in mingw) to the linking phase.

Comment: I tried adding it to the C++ package thing and compile: "sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in"

Comment: Right, then you need to get a "better" version of gcc for your setup.

Comment: @Mats Petersson if his OS is 32bit then he'll still only get 2GB max, maybe 3 depending on fragmentation

Comment: @paulm: Yes, but the title says Windows 7 64 - as we have no evidence of the contrary, I'd say that "near 4GB" of allocations are possible, although a single large allocation may still be difficult to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

- You need a 64-bit compiler. You can install one using [this installer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe/download). Note you can also install a 32-bit compiler with the same installer.
- For 32-bit applications: set a bit in the executable file that signals to Windows it can use up to 4GB of memory. To do this, add `-Wl,--large-address-aware` to you linker command. This will give you 3GB on 32-bit Windows, and 4GB on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: @AGuy what command did you use (exactly)? Note that's the small letter `L` (ell, the 12th letter in the alphabet).

Comment: I just added "-Wl" to the C++ packages thing where the command line arguments are held (and yes lower L)

Comment: Also I get a random error when using the installer for 64 bit compiler (no helpful msg -- just ERROR)

Comment: @AGuy I have no idea what that means. I get the installer error as well I'll report it to the mailing list. In any case, you can get a 64-bit toolchain from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/4.9.1/threads-posix/seh/). Just extract it and add the `bin` directory to PATH.

Comment: Okay, I installed it and added the bin dir to Path. I do C++ --version and it still says 4.7.2?

Comment: @AGuy does `where gcc` give you the right answer? Otherwise you added to the wrong end of PATH or not at all. If you changed it in the Windows advanced system settings dialog, be sure to restart the application (or log off and on again).

Comment: ok I think it works. Apparently I have to add "-std=c++11" flag too. so I can add -std=c++11, -o2, -wl, --large-address-aware?

Comment: Hm still unrecognized Wl (I am doing this from command line now)

Comment: @AGuy I'm going to ask one last time: what is the exact command you execute? (copy paste it)

Comment: I got the g++ thing working (g++ --version is right). Now trying to get the flags working

Comment: Right now doing "g++ blah.cpp -std=c++11 -o2"

Comment: And what happens if you add `-Wl,--large-address-aware`?

Comment: Apparently I may not need to do anything. The program seems to be using > 5 GB now